# query cosmos db without enabling cross partition query

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

When query cosmos db, there is an option of setting  enableCrossPartitionQuery as true. 
I am wondering what happens that if I did not set it? Which partition will be used for the query?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your collection is partitioned, then the query,update, delete opeartions need partition key setting.

If you don't set, perhaps you could see below error:

[image]

For this situation, if you don't want to set any partition key or you don't know which partition the row data belongs to, then you could set `enableCrossPartitionQuery= true` to avoid the error. If you set `enableCrossPartitionQuery= true`, it means this request will scan all the partitions to filter the data. Of course,it's query performance is bound to decline.

BTW,if your data size is small,i think the impact may be small. However,if the data size is large, i suggest you trying your best to avoid setting this property.

---

I tested the sample project : https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-cosmos-db-sql-api-nodejs-getting-started.git and it doesn't require partition key indeed when the container is partitioned.

However, based on the statements in the [cosmos db rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/common-cosmosdb-rest-request-headers) :

[image]

I tested java sdk and it requires the partition key when i query partitioned container. Anyway,i want to say that if you met the error which indicates the lack of partition key, you could try to add the property `enableCrossPartitionQuery = true` to solve it. Mostly, i still suggest you providing partition key for the query performance.

Comment: Hi Jay, Thanks for your reply.  I just find a document from microsoft as below : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/create-sql-api-nodejs    . In this article, the query does not include any partition-key.

Comment: @RichardD You're welcome,RichardD. I‘m afraid that the following code does not match the above documents screenshot (including PK). Anyway, i could do a test for you with the sample data and sample code. Give me some time.

Comment: @RichardD Hi,does my answer helps you?

Comment: Hi Jay, thanks for your help and testing.  It is strange that cosmos db behavior different for Java and nodejs and microsoft's document sucks.  Although it is helpful that using enableCrossPartitionQuery to resolve kind of lack of partition key errors, I still wondering what happens when not using partition key in nodejs. Does it  search all partitions by default ?

Comment: Hi Jay, BTW, I can not find any js query sample which using partition key. Have you found any sample code? thanks